# Rate Limiting Individual URL Requests

Tags: iptables

I have a Flask application I’m developing that relies heavily on external website interaction and is initiated by the end-user.  If I leave the application without any sort of bandwidth control/rate limiting then this application may be abused by actors with nefarious intentions.

My goal is a fairly simple 2 stage approach:

1. Rate limit individual IP sources from performing more than `x` number of connections a minute.  This can be easily achieved with `iptables`.  [Here’s a similar example to my goal:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140796/54341)

   ```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 \
      --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
   ```
2. Rate limit the applications ability to perform more than `x` number of lookups *per URL*.  Example:

   ```
    APP ---- 10 pps --->  stackexchange.com   PERMIT
    APP ---- 25 pps --->  google.com          DENY / 15 SECOND BACKOFF
   ```

So far as I can tell, `iptables` has no way of tracking separate URLs.  It’s only able to rate limit these connections as a whole.  That also doesn't seem like the only limitation to what I'm trying to achieve.  If there were a way to setup `iptables` in this way, it might provide some issues with my web application since these requests are user-initiated.

I’m using Flask, a viable option might be using a [`before_request` hook](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) and manually tracking these destinations with a data store such as Redis.  However, this is pretty high up in the stack to be dealing with connections in this manner.  What I really need (or think I do) is an intelligent firewall application that can dissect requests in a custom way and close connections when certain breakpoints have been reached.

Is there any way to achieve what I’m trying to do?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iptables` deals with the Internet and Transport layers (in the Internet model) or alternatively layers 3 and 4 in the OSI model, with a few exceptions (filtering on MAC addresses, NAT protocol helpers).

URIs are part of the Application layer. `iptables` doesn't deal with them.

You could use iptables to direct all your outgoing TCP port 80 traffic through a web proxy, which could do your rate limiting (e.g., maybe [Squid's delay pools](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DelayPools) could do it. Or Apache probably can with `mod_proxy`.) Doing this with HTTPS is more difficult (though maybe you can just configure your app to use a web proxy, which would be a better approach than a transparent proxy anyway).

**But you really should move both of your rate limits in to your application.** The reason being the UX you're setting up is *terrible*; "connection refused" fails to explain at all what is happening. It'd be *much* better for your users if you instead gave an error page explaining that they're making requests too fast, who to contact for support, maybe give an option to solve a CAPTCHA to continue, etc.

It's reasonable to have a connection rate limit on incoming connections, but it should be to protect the app from falling over due to a DoS attack—so many requests that your app can't even serve the rate exceeded error page to the user. It should be a fair bit higher than when you start serving the error page (and maybe should be a global limit, not a per-source-IP limit). Note that if your app is running through a web server and/or reverse proxy, you can likely configure incoming rate limits there (instead of via iptables)—and do *very* cheap rejects by sending a static error page, and not even passing the request to your app.